# Converting HTML to Wordpress > Keep .htm .html _ in URLs

Tags: wordpress, url, .htaccess

thank you very much in advance for helping.

I am converting a static HTML website to Wordpress.

The HTML site is doing very well in Google and it has been agreed that we need to keep existing URLs in the Wordpress site. We do not want to change names and have permanent redirects.

The existing site has got most pages with .htm and some pages with .html, but WP does not support this by default. We found a plug-in to add .htm or .html but it applies either one extension or the other to the whole site so it will not suit us.

Likewise, we have _ (underscore) in URLs which is also not supported by WP.

It has been suggested to us to use .htaccess rules to solve both problems, but we do not know where to start.

Can you kindly give us some help. Thanks in advance for helping a brother in need.

Comment: can you give examples of the urls you want to go from and to?  e.g. example.com/A_b_c.html > example.com/a-b-c/

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Advanced Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/) plugin. Then just add the .htm or .html to the permalink when writing/editing the post.

Answer (score 0):

for underscoring you should take a look at this [How do I use underscore in a wordpress permalink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728300/how-do-i-use-underscore-in-a-wordpress-permalink)

but for .htm and .html you can acheive that with out using a plugin, just by going to the permalink settings. but you are going to have to stick with either .htm or .html (choose one)